# Google barchart don't display single horizontal bar when value is in the millions

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-barchart

Barchart doesn’t show a single bar item when the value is in the millions.
Can see this code snippet below in jsFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/mharri117/zwycshvm/187/

HTML code

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barChart"/>
```

Javascript code

```
 google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  
  function drawChart() {
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string');
        data.addColumn('number');
        data.addColumn({ 'type': 'string', 'role': 'style' });
        data.addRows([
          ['name1',3442222,'color: #fcba03'],// This will not show the bar
          //['name2',34422,'color: #fcba03'],// uncomment this line and comment out line 11 and 
           everything works fine
        ]);

      // Instantiate and draw the chart.
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
      chart.draw(data, null);
    }
```

Comment: looks like a bug that should be [reported to google](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues)...

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, Posted this with google here https://github.com/google/charts/issues/782

Comment: you can at least get the bar to appear by setting `hAxis.minValue` to zero in the config options, or some other number much lower than the value -- [https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/08xu5gzf/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/08xu5gzf/1/)

Comment: That's a great workaround WhiteHat! Added hAxis.minValue and it solved the single bar item not showing.