# Google Chart Bar chart is rendered outside of the chart canvas

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

When there is a high value like one million, the bar chart is not rendered. If you inspect the  element is with a `x` value too negative:

[image]

Here is the code that I used to reproduce this issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
      google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      
      function drawChart() {
        const data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        
        data.addColumn('string', 'Expense');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Paid');
        data.addRows([
          //['Amazon', 100_000] //it works
          ['Amazon', 1_000_000]
        ]);
      
        const chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
        
        chart.draw(data, null);
      }
      
    </script>
    <title>Google Charts Issue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="barChart"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this issue? I've just was able to solve using a [logScale](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes), but I cannot use this solution because it would be complicate to explain to the app users.

Comment: see comments under question here --> [Google barchart don't display single horizontal bar when value is in the millions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940209/google-barchart-dont-display-single-horizontal-bar-when-value-is-in-the-million)

Comment: thank you! It's the same issue and the `hAxis.minValue` workaround also worked :)